# Add maximum possible edges to the graph with nodes capacity

Tags: algorithm, graph

Problem: given N nodes, each of them has a limit for it's own degree, for example degree of the node (1) can not be higher that 10 (but can be less, of course), degree of the node (2) can not be higher that 3, etc. On these nodes build graph with maximum possible edges.

Would be happy to see any hints/recommendations.

EIDT: Graph should be simple :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no other constraint on which vertices can be connected, a greedy algorithm should work here: Connect whichever two unconnected vertices have the highest remaining degree, until no such pair exists. This can be done efficiently with an array of vertices dynamically sorted by remaining degree.

Comment: Thank you! Seems to work :) 

Just a few additional questions, may be there's an easy way to do this:
Is it possible to estimate the max. number of edges to be added without actually adding them?

Comment: @Nadine that should be asked as a new question.

Comment: The question doesn't specify the graph must be simple, does it? That said, I think this answer is still basically right with the associated adjustments. Loops and duplicated edges don't seem to cause problems, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah I posted an answer to that effect before the edit :) I wouldn't put it past instructors to ask trick questions, never hurts to try the easy answer first.

Comment: I found kinda contra-example: considering 6 nodes with capacities 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, maximum amount of edges could be added is 7, hoverer this algorithm doest always give a correct answer. Despite this, if instead of maximum amount of edges we are looking for the minimum possible (kind of worst case) it works good!

Answer (score 0):

If the graph doesn't have to be simple (the question doesn't specify) then just add duplicate self loops to exhaust all but at most one available endpoint at each node. Then, pair off nodes. You will be left with at most one unused endpoint; the number of edges is trivially the sum of endpoint allowances, divided by two, rounded down.

Comment: Yes, It should be simple. I've just added it to the description!

Comment: @Nadine Never hurts to try the simple answer first :) I'll leave this here in case others with a similar question are not so contrained.